# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer - Eclips 2020-06

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

For running JTable in Java Swing at  Eclips 2020-06, imported rs2xml.jar file. But after that, while running the program, the following error is occurring.

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for E:\Progrm Learning\JAVA\Student\rs2xml.jar
> Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: JDOMAbout$Author.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)

Answer (score 3):

`rs2xml.jar` contains a class in the default package which is not allowed when using [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System).

In *Project > Properties: Java Build Path*, tab *Libraries* move `rs2xml.jar` from the *Modulepath* to the *Classpath* and in the project, in the source folder, in the default package delete your `module-info.java` file to not use JPMS.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @howlger works but if after deleting your module-info.java file your
src file gives error then you could start a new project and while creating new project select don't create module-info

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score -1):

Nice question.

`rs2xml.jar` contains a class in the default package which is not allowed when using JPMS.

In `Project > Properties: Java Build Path > Libraries`, move `rs2xml.jar` from the Modulepath to the Classpath.

Then in the project, in the source folder, and in the default package delete your `module-info.java` file in order to not use JPMS.

Comment: the is a plain copy (minus formatting/styling) of the howlger's answer .. or in other words: plagiate == spam!